# The Definition of Regular Languages

Tags: regex, computer-science, grammar, regular-language

I have tried, and burned my brain to understand the definition of Regular Languages in [Discrete Mathematics and its Applications(Rosen)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072880082) without reaching the goal of understanding why the definition is like that in this book. On page(789), I am *rephrasing* the definition:

**Type 3 grammars are defined as:**

```
w1 --> w2
```

**Where w1 is a non-terminal, and w2 is of the form:**

```
w2 = aB
w2 = a
```

**Where B is a non-terminal, and a is a terminal. A special case is when w1 is the starting symbol and w2 is lambda(the empty string):**

```
w1 = S
S --> lambda
```

Two questions I couldn't find an answer for. First, Why can't **w2** be of the form **Ba**. Second, Why **lambda** is only allowed for the starting symbol ***only***. The book states that, regular languages are equivalent to Finite State Automaton, and we can easily see that a we can build FSA for both cases. I took a look at other resources, and these restrictions don't exist in these resources.

Comment: Did you check on whether the book has any errata?

Comment: @David M No, I didn't do that but I will do it now. Interestingly, on page(795) exercise#19 (i, j) exactly are solved according to this definition.

Comment: I just have checked the errata of the 6th ed. and without finding any thing:http://highered.mcgraw-hill.com/sites/dl/free/0072880082/299357/Rosen_errata.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First, Why can't w2 be of the form Ba.

Take the following grammar with W as starting symbol:

```
W -> lambda
W -> aX
X -> Wb
```

it generates {a<sup>n</sup> b<sup>n</sup> : n natural } which is not a regular language. So this restriction is essential, if you want to generate only regular languages. Alternatively, you may allow w2 = Ba, but *forbid* rules of kind w2 = aB - this also gives regular languages. That grammar will build a word "backwards".

If you allow both types of rules, you'll get a class known as [linear languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar).

> Second, Why lambda is only allowed for the starting symbol only.

This is not a neccesary restriction.

You may eliminate all uses of lambda for nonterminal symbols: take some rule W -> lambda, remove it, and replace all rules U -> aW with U -> aW and U -> a. Obviously you cannot eliminate use of lambda for terminal symbol (the language won't produce empty word anymore).

So, every type 3 grammar that uses lambda in many places can be "normalized" to a grammar that uses lambda only for the starting symbol.